Cloned React Native project doesn't configure routing properly and open default page
I created React Native project with Expo, define routes using app folder. It opens correctly and displays content. I pushed the changes on Github, cloned it and when tried to run it, it opened the default page:
enter image description here
Also my local project structure looks like that:
enter image description here
I decided to create index file in app folder, but it didn't help. ( I don't know why I need it, expo by default doesn't create this file)
Also I run npm cache clean, npm install and tried to run again. The same.
